# Is SELECT INTO T-SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm working in a project where I have been explicitly required to not use T-SQL syntax. The application we are using supports T-SQL but we are not allowed to use it to avoid potential migration issues.

My question is: is the SELECT ... INTO statement T-SQL or SQL? If it is T-SQL, is there a specific SQL query to copy an existing table into a new one? (I have tried with CREATE TABLE AS .. FROM but it doesn't work).

Sounds like a very basic question but I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere. Thus, in addition to the question above, it would be very helpful to know if there is a guide/dictionary/website that collects only the standard SQL syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `SELECT ... FROM ... INTO` works with SQL Server.  What is your question?

Comment: My question is if that syntax would work in an environment that does not support T-SQL. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK most SQL databases would support it.  Which database, other than SQL Server, do you have in mind?

Comment: I'm not sure TBH. My knowledge in this field is quite limited. We were simply asked not to use T-SQL as it might not be supported in a different enviroment. But I understand from your answer that SELECT .. INTO syntax is not T-SQL exclusive

Comment: https://developer.mimer.com/sql-validator-99/ validates ANSI SQL conformance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they recommend you to use ANSI SQL, instead of T-SQL (SQL Server) or PL-SQL (ORACLE). Considering it as common requirement, every database vendor provide their own way of implementing this requirement. When you use ANSI SQL, you will not have migration issues, when you move from one database vendor to another database vendor.

**SQL SERVER**

```
SELECT * INTO new_table
FROM existing_table
```

**ORACLE & ANSI-SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE new_table 
AS SELECT * FROM existing_table
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Sorry for my mistake. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

> is SELECT INTO TSQL or SQL?

Neither. The MySQL documentation claims that SELECT INTO is a Sybase extension to standard sql. As such I don't think you can accurately say it's either of these, but you can say that it's neither. It is indeed used in T-SQL, as well as some other database vendor products, to create a table from a query. The SQL standard says that queries with that goal should be formed as `CREATE TABLE blah AS SELECT ...`. Oracle/MySQL, for example, use the standard form though you can see them use SELECT INTO in a different context, to assign data to variables in stored procedures

If you want to avoid use of this non standard syntax when creating and populating a table then you'll have to:

```
CREATE TABLE blah (column spec to match query output)
INSERT blah (select query here)
```

But then you run into nuances like "sqlserver calls it datetime/datetime2 but oracle calls it date/timestamp"

And ultimately you'll probably get into a situation where you just can't use one form of sql to do all you want..

I'd imagine most libraries that do data access on multiple underlying databases have mechanisms to use vendor specific terminology where required

Answer (score 0):

From the answers, it appears you might need to specify which SELECT INTO you're talking about.  The other answers seem to suggest there exists some kind of SELECT ... INTO <***table-name***> when there is also a kind of SELECT ... INTO <***local-variable-name list***>.  The latter is used in embedded SQL for making SQL interact with variables of the host language program.  I'm not certain but that variant may also be used in the part of the SQL language that deals with procedures written in SQL (the SQL/PSM part of the standard).

A "reference" that covers "only the standard SQL syntax" is, in principle, the ISO standard document itself, only available by purchase from ISO (and yes, it's ISO ***not*** ANSI - ANSI does nothing more than rubberstamping the ISO document after removing all the names of non-US contributors).  And not the easiest kind of literature.  There are "draft" versions floating around on the internet that might deviate from the published final standards.  E.g. http://www.wiscorp.com/sql200n.zip.  Note that this is a SQL:2008 draft.  Current standard version is SQL:2011.  And it's several thousands of pages, so I guess that covers your question "Is all the syntax covered in w3schools standard SQL".  (Hint : no)

Comment: Actually the current version of the standard is SQL:2016

Comment: Aaaaaaaargh.  Why do I always forget that one ?  Didn't see it pass by when it happened I suppose.